# Attempted to load class "OpenBundle" from namespace "vCoin\OpenBundle"

Tags: php, symfony

I have illogical problem.

I use command

> php bin/console generate:bundle

to generate new bundle in my project, but symfony tell me this error.

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 19:
Attempted to load class "OpenBundle" from namespace "vCoin\OpenBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

this is my AppKernel.php

```
$bundles = [
        //...
        new vCoin\OpenBundle\OpenBundle(),
    ];
```

and this is Bundle class

```
namespace vCoin\OpenBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class OpenBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

I don't look where is the problem ..

The version of symfony which I use is 3.2.11 and this is my file structure.

```
|-src 
|---vCoin
|------OpenBundle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It's a problem of composer

Try this inside composer.json into autoload:

```
"psr-4": {
    "": "src/"
},
```

And after inside your console launch:

```
composer dump-autoload
```